# Recursive RegEx to match keys and name

Tags: c#, regex, recursive-regex

I have the strings, `["02-03-2013#3rd Party Fuel", "-1#Archived", "2#06-23-2013#Newswire"]`, which I want to break down into several parts. These strings are prefixed with date and index keys and contain a name.

I've design a `RegEx` that matches each key properly. However, if I want to match the index key, date key, and name in fell swoop. Only the first key is found. It seems the recursive group isn't working as I expect it should.

```
private const string INDEX_KEY_REGEX = @"(?<index>-?\d+)";
private const string DATE_KEY_REGEX = @"(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-\d{4})";
private const string KEY_SEARCH_REGEX = @"(?<R>(?:^|(?<=#))({0})#(?(R)))(?<name>.*)";

private string Name = "2#06-23-2013#Newswire"
... = Regex.Replace(
    Name,
    String.Format(KEY_SEARCH_REGEX, INDEX_KEY_REGEX + "|" + DATE_KEY_REGEX),
    "${index}, ${date}, ${name}"
);

// These are the current results for all strings when set into the Name variable.

// Correct Result: ", 02-03-2013, 3rd Party Fuel"
// Correct Result: "-1, , Archived"
// Invalid Result: "2, , 06-23-2013#Newswire"
// Should be: "2, 06-23-2013, Newswire"
```

Does a keen eye see something I've missed?

---

**Final Solution As I Needed It**

It turns out I didn't need a recursive group. I simply needed 0 to many sequence. Here is the full `RegEx`.

```
(?:(?:^|(?<=#))(?:(?<index>-?\d+)|(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(\d{2}|\d{4})))#)*(?<name>.*)
```

And, the segmented `RegEx`

```
private const string INDEX_REGEX = @"(?<index>-?\d+)";
private const string DATE_REGEX = @"(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(\d{2}|\d{4}))";
private const string KEY_WRAPPER_REGEX = @"(?:^|(?<=#))(?:{0})#";
private const string KEY_SEARCH_REGEX = @"(?:{0})*(?<name>.*)";
```

Comment: It works for this test case if you remove the `^|` test.  What's the intent of that?

Comment: That was to ensure the keys are always at the beginning and never at the end or having an undermined string before them. I'll test without it but I think it will break the stated requirement. I'll see what I find.

Comment: So with my testing the following results `2#, 06-23-2013, Newswire` and `-1#Archived` (no matches). So that's farther from the desired.

Comment: What's the desired result for all three of your tests?  I just know the one.

Comment: I've added the current results to the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the individual regexs break down into this:

Index: Capture a single positive or negative number.  (-, 0 or 1 rep, followed by one or more digits)

date: Specified date string, separated with -.  No allowance made for any other date format.  Note, the leading '#' and trailing '#' are not handled, it specifically captures the date, and only the date

R: beginning of line OR #, then the formatting replacement to make it one BIG regex...then another #, specified.  then a conditional with no false...and true doesn't do anything either.

name: capture whatever is left.

final result, compiled into a single regex....
two captures: R and name.
R: (4 parts)
R-1: Match either beginning of line or #
R-2: Get EITHER (but never both) Date or Index
R-3: match #
R-4: Empty Conditional Expression
name: match whatever is left.

The issue seems to be that you are not matching both index and date

**final edit, working regex**

Bear with me, this thing is nasty.  You have to account for all 4 possibilities, or it wont match every possible case.  I couldn't figure out any way to generalize it.

```
(?:(?<index>-?\d+(?!\d-))#(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|:3[01])-\d{4})|(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|:3[01])-\d{4})#(?<index>-?\d+)|(?!-?\d+#)(?<date>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|:3[01])-\d{4})|(?<index>-?\d+)(?!#(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|:3[01])-\d{4}))#(?<name>.*)
```

ugly, i know.  It has 4 initial conditions.

```
1a) capture <index>#<date>  OR
1b) capture <date>#<index>  OR
1c) capture <index> only, as long as its not followed by a date  OR
1d) capture <date> only, as long as its not preceded by an index
...
2) match but ignore #
3) capture <name>
```

works in all 4 cases.

**Final: Final Edit**

There is a way to do this using 3 regexs instead of just 1, which might end up being cleaner.

```
//note: index MIGHT be preceeded by, and is ALWAYS followed by, a #
indexRegex = @"((?=#)?(?<!\d|-)-?\d+(?=#))";
//same with date
dateRegex = @"((?=#)?(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-\d{4}(?=#))";
//then name
nameRegex = @"(?:.*#){1,2}(.*)";
```

run them each separately against a replace to get the individual variables, then rebuild the string.

Comment: That looks mostly correct but doesn't the `+` in the `INDEX_KEY_REGEX` signify that the regex will match at least one or more `\d`.

Comment: Currently, that only works for a single digit index, and might mess up the date...still working on it.

Comment: This is extremely close to what is needed, however, it doesn't account for cases where the date key may be before the index key, `06-23-2013#2#Newswire`. This is the reason I thought to try a recursive statement. How would you handle this? Sorry for not explaining it earlier.

Comment: @roydukkey - Your data is **ugly**.  But that's what Regexs are for.

Comment: oo, never realized that date and index could reverse their order there...very nasty...are those the only 2 that could move?

Comment: @Nevyn - I'm impressed.  Nice job.

Comment: @Nevyn Like wise, I'm impressed too. Thank you!

Comment: @Bobson truth be told Im still annoyed that I couldn't find a way to get it any shorter, that thing is ugly.  If anyone else can figure out a way to shrink it, feel free.